# ResponseParseException:OK - HttpBuilder - RestCLient

Tags: httpbuilder

I see the below exception when I submit my request: 
groovyx.net.http.ResponseParseException: OK
Request: 
def response = new RestClient().post([ "http://endpoint/path", 
contentType: ContentType.JSON, 
body:
{"s":a, "b":"af"}
])
Groovy version: 2.3.10 
HttpBuilder version : 0.7.1
I know that the server responds 200 :OK for this request. I tested it using Advanced Rest Client chrome app. 
I referred the thread http://www.groovy-lang.org/mailing-lists.html#nabble-td333800 but not helpful. Please let me know how I can resolve this issue.

Comment: Could you please somebody look into my issue?

Comment: Post your full code.